If one is arrested, but has a baby/pet in their house, what are they supposed to do?
Rob steps out of his house real quick to commit a robbery, and the police stop him and bring him into the station and put him in jail, pending a trial. But Rob has a 6-month old baby at home, or perhaps just a cat/dog at home that they have to attend to to feed, etc.. What is Rob supposed to do? If he tells the police, will they send someone to his house to take care of the baby/pet? And if Rob doesn't tell the police, is he liable for what happens to the baby/pet?
Assume that Rob has no one in his life he can call to help with his pet/baby.

In many places leaving a 6-months-old unattended would be already a reason for the social services to interfere and take the child. It may also trigger abandonment charges or something like that. Apart from that - Rob has the right for a phone call, doesn't he?

I'm not sure combining the "baby" and "pet" scenarios is good. I'm fairly certain these are completely different circumstances (in that I am afraid police won't care much about your dog going without food for a day). More interesting may be "baby or other dependent that requires constant help", such as an elderly parent or a mentally handicapped brother.

@RogerV. The last line stipulates that there's no one he can usefully call with that phone call.

@Barmar he could call firemen, animal nursery, social services, etc. - this is not covered by the last line.

A better example might be that he steps outside to the letterbox to receive the day's mail and is arrested for causes completely outside his control.  It would seem unjust to prosecute him for child endangerment because he happens to resemble the suspect in a robbery he had nothing whatsoever to do with.

Europe: police tries to find an adult where they can leave the baby (both legally and safely). It might be even a reason to avoid the arrest of the mother (depending on the seriousness of the case). Youth protection is automatically alarmed as the police see the baby. If nothing else works, the baby can be in the prison with his mother until 1yo, there is a special regime for that.

canada
Police could allow the accused to make arrangements for the care of the child or pets by family or friends, either directly, or through the accused's lawyer.
If that is not an option, they would inform child and family services to deal with the care of the child.
They could have the pet transferred to a local animal care organization.

Do they have a duty to do so? What if the police don't do anything? Will they be liable if the child or pet suffers or even dies?

I'm not an expert in this area, but from my understanding US procedure works exactly like this as well: children would be processed by Child Protective Services, and be put into the custody of appropriate relations or handled internally until the child could either be returned or put into foster care (depending on the situation).

@vsz Police have control of most of the evidence that would incriminate them, and there's qualified immunity too. If police as a group doesn't do something, very unlikely to lead to consequences. But if an individual working for the police clearly goes against department policy and expectation, they could be criminally liable.
